# How can I change my extension_dir or confirm that it is set correctly?

Tags: php, apache2.4

When I do phpinfo(), it says this:

```
extension_dir C:\php\ext C:\php\ext
```

I thought this was determined from within php.ini, but if I change the line in php.ini to this:

```
extension_dir = "ext2"
```

Even if I restart apache, and even restart my pc, phpinfo() still shows:

```
extension_dir C:\php\ext C:\php\ext
```

Where is this "c:\php\ext" coming from?

My server (Apache 2.4) is not loading php drivers correctly, so I want to confirm that this value is not being used in this kind of way: "c:\php\c:\php\ext"

So I'd like to try to change my extension_dir to actually show as "ext" in the phpinfo(), which is how I've seen it in screenshots of other people's phpinfo().

How can I change it? Because php.ini is clearly not affecting it.

Comment: Does `Loaded Configuration File` match the file you're editing?

Comment: Loaded Configuration File (none) - Wow, thanks - now I'm trying to fix this

Comment: Thanks, I added this in my apache's httpd.conf: PHPIniDir "C:/php"

Answer (score -1):

Try without the quotation marks, like in the [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/it/install.windows.extensions.php).